# Email solution to prevent kids from seeing graphic notifications

Tags: email, macbook

My girlfriend likes me to send her explicit emails, in terms of the language and sometimes photo attachments. The problem is that she lets her kids use her MacBook (for some reason?) and they see the pop up notifications of her emails.

We don't want to delay or censor my emails, and we also want the pop up notifications. However what would be great is if there were some app or trick to censor just the pop up notifications.

Comment: Change her password on her OS X account, create a new account for the kids to use.

Comment: @ivanivan Thanks, makes sense to me but we did that 3 years ago and she won't go for it because she finds it too much of a hassle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BEST answer is to have a kids logon as well as an adult one - this would also prevent the children from spending any money online - this might be an intensive to make the effort worth while.

You will have to test but many pop-up notifiers only show the first few lines of any message. If you format your messages as:

> Hi Darling,
>
> XXX
>
> (blank lines)
>
> (more blank lines)
>
> The saucy bit!

Then it is likely that the pop-up will not include that saucy bit - of course it will not stop them from viewing the email by clicking on the pop-up.

Comment: Thanks Steve I think this will work for me but I will need to test it per your suggestion and I will come back soon and mark this is the answer. However with respect I don't think that the second log on addresses pop-up notifications at all so maybe we can remove that piece of the answer. Anyway thanks again I will go to the Amish market and then I will be back and I will test this. Thanks!!